# How can I get data from a Cross domain API

Tags: c#, javascript, json, api

I'm trying to get data from an API in a different domain but I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'localhost' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I tried to add this in the header but it still doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.bitstamp.net
</head>
<body>
<script src="Index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
var ticker = "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/";
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: ticker,
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    scriptCharset: "utf-8"
});
```

I can not use **JSONP** because the website doesn't support this.
How can I receive the data from the API with JSON on a different domain?
I would like to do this with **JavaScript or C#**.

Comment: It's not really that *header*, it's the request header set by the server you're contacting, so if it's not your server, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add class to you project and mark your Controllers with it

```
public class AllowCrossSiteAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
       if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null)
         actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        }
    }
}
```

then in Controller add to controller method option because first call will be to options to get if CROSS is allowd

```
[System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

(Please not that here you allow all domain but you can replace "*" with list of your domains)

Or using web config (But it will be for all controllers)

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Option for asp.net web forms could be

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Comment: But i think that web config option could be solution for both, so you should try but i am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

there is a security impact if you allow * with CORS. A script from any other website will be able to get the data from your api on logged in users browser.
never use * with CORS, whitelist your allowed host instead.